OpenSSH with admin user
I am setting up an OpenSSH sFTP server.
I want to create a sFTP Admin user that can navigate all the folders and move files.
My approach is the following:

Create the other users (let's call it user_1) and directory

sudo useradd user1

sudo passwd user1

sudo mkdir -p /var/datadrive/sftp-server/user1/user1

sudo chown user1:user1/var/datadrive/sftp-server/user1/user1

sudo chmod 775 /var/datadrive/sftp-server/user1/user1


Add the default group to the folders (so that even if sftp_admin creates a subfolder inside /user1, user1 can still write to it

sudo chmod g+s /var/datadrive/sftp-server/user1/user1
sudo chown :user1 /var/datadrive/sftp-server/user1/user1


Add the sftp_admin user:

sudo useradd sftp_admin
sudo passwd sftp_admin
sudo usermod -g user1 sftp_admin


Add the sshd_config

Match User sftp_admin
   ChrootDirectory /var/datadrive/sftp-server/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Match Group user1
   ChrootDirectory /var/datadrive/sftp-server/user1
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   X11Forwarding no

This works fine. However if I set the group user 1 on the sshd file first it doesnt work (sftp_admin gets jailed to the /user1 folder). I am guessing by taking advantage of the top-down behavior the sftp_admin configs apply first than the group ones so it is rooted to the sftp-server folder.
Is my approach correct? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Does user1 group have multiple users?

user1 group only has user1 and sftp_admin as members
